# Lost SSH access to DigitalOcean server. How to retrieve the database?

Tags: database, ghost

So I've changed my Macbook and lost the previous public key.
My blog is hosted on DigitalOcean.
I'm going to migrate my blog, but I can't access my database. How can I retrieve the database?

Your answer is much appreciated!

Comment: You need to provide more information before we can help. Where is your ghost blog located? On your macbook itself? Public key for what? Github?

Comment: Updated the description.
My blog is hosted on DigitalOcean. Public key for SSH access to the server.

Comment: @coder101 - this question isn't a good fit for stackoverflow, because it's not about software development; it's about systems administration. You might have better luck on SuperUser.

Comment: @antiduh makes a good point - it might be better on SuperUser as a question

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to login to the server via SSH using your user password or using the console on the control panel. SSH keys are stored in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file. Now you can remove your SSH or replace it with a new SSH key. Once you have done that, you will be able to join using the new SSH key.